# Two very similar table views have different scrolling quality

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, tableview

I have two UITableViewControllers that both contain very similar cells (each cell class has 2 UIImageViews and 2 UILabels). The first view controller is written in Objective-C and implemented purely in code. The second view controller is written in Swift and is laid out in a storyboard.

My issue is that the first view controller jerks when it scrolls to the top while the second view controller is perfectly smooth when it scrolls to the top. Here is a [video](https://youtu.be/ZukGAQvR2VM) of it.

**cellForRowAtIndexPath of first TableViewController**:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

LYRConversation *conversation = _searching && _filteredDataSource.count ? [_filteredDataSource objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] : [_dataSource objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

if (conversation.participants.count > 2) {
    ConversationListGroupCell *cell = (ConversationListGroupCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:GROUP_CELL_REUSE_ID forIndexPath:indexPath];
    [self configureGroupCell:cell atIndexPath:indexPath conversation:conversation];
    return cell;
}

ConversationListCell *cell = (ConversationListCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CELL_REUSE_ID forIndexPath:indexPath];
[self configureCell:cell atIndexPath:indexPath conversation:conversation];

return cell; 
}

-(void)configureCell:(ConversationListCell *)conversationCell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath conversation:(LYRConversation *)conversation
{
    [conversationCell updateAvatarWithUrl:[NSURL URLWithString:[self avatarStringUrlForConversation:conversation]]];
    [conversationCell updateTitle:[self titleForConversation:conversation]];
    [conversationCell updateUnreadMessageIndicator:conversation];
    NSArray *otherParticipants = [[PersistentCache sharedCache] cachedUsersForUserIDs:conversation.participants];
    conversationCell.preview.text = [((PFUser *)otherParticipants.lastObject) objectForKey:@"jobTitle"];
    [UIView updateStatusIndicatorOfConversation:otherParticipants statusIndicator:conversationCell.status];
}

-(void)configureGroupCell:(ConversationListGroupCell *)conversationGroupCell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath conversation:(LYRConversation *)conversation {
NSArray *urls = [self avatarStringUrlsForConversation:conversation];
if (urls.count == conversation.participants.count - 1) {
    NSURL *url1 = [NSURL URLWithString:urls[0]];
    if(url1 != NULL) {
        downloadImageThenSetForImageView(conversationGroupCell.avatar1, url1);
    }
    NSURL *url2 = [NSURL URLWithString:urls[1]];
    if (url2 != NULL) {
        downloadImageThenSetForImageView(conversationGroupCell.avatar2, url2);
    }
    if (urls.count > 2) {
        NSURL *url3 = [NSURL URLWithString:urls[2]];
        if (url3 != NULL) {
            downloadImageThenSetForImageView(conversationGroupCell.avatar3, url3);
        }
        conversationGroupCell.avatar3.hidden = NO;
    }
    if (urls.count > 3){
        conversationGroupCell.plusOne.hidden = NO;
        conversationGroupCell.plusOne.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"+%lu", urls.count - 3];
    }
}

conversationGroupCell.title.text = [self titleForConversation:conversation];

if (conversation.lastMessage.isUnread) {
    //[self.unreadMessageIndicator setImage:[ConversationListCell unreadBlue] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [conversationGroupCell.unreadMessageIcon setImage:[Assets unreadBlue]];
}
else {
    //[self.unreadMessageIndicator setImage:[ConversationListCell unreadGray] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [conversationGroupCell.unreadMessageIcon setImage:[Assets unreadGray]];
}

NSString *idOfLastSender = conversation.lastMessage.sender.userID;
NSString *lastMessageText = NULL;
if ([idOfLastSender isEqualToString:self.layerClient.authenticatedUserID]) {
    lastMessageText = @"You";
}
else {
    lastMessageText = [[PersistentCache sharedCache] resolvedFullNamesFromParticipants:@[idOfLastSender]].firstObject;
}
conversationGroupCell.preview.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ 

sent last message", lastMessageText];
}
```

**cellForRowAtIndexPath of second TableViewController:**

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CallLogCell
{
    guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(CellIdentifiers.PhoneCell.rawValue, forIndexPath: indexPath) as? CallLogCell else {
        return CallLogCell()
    }
    configureCell(cell, indexPath: indexPath)
    return cell
}

func configureCell(cell: CallLogCell, indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    let callParticipantInfo = CallLog.callLogDataSource[indexPath.row]
    // TODO: Add all these to the cell class as methods
    // TODO: Make sure UI looks okay if any of this stuff is nil

    // Set Name
    guard let callParticipant = callParticipantInfo[CallLogDataSourceIndices.Object] as? PFUser else {
        return
    }
    cell.nameLabel.text     = callParticipant.fullName()

    // Set Image
    let imageUrlString = callParticipant[ParseKeys.ImageUrl.rawValue] as? String ?? ""
    if let imageUrl       = NSURL(string: imageUrlString) {
        downloadImageThenSetForImageView(cell.picture, imageUrl)
    }
    else {
        cell.picture.image = Assets.placeholder()
    }

    // Set Status
    let status = callParticipant[ParseKeys.Status.rawValue] as? NSNumber ?? NSNumber.statusCodeUnknown()
    cell.statusIndicator.backgroundColor = UIColor.PNGStatusColorForStatusCode(status.integerValue)

    // Set Missed call
    let missedCall = callParticipantInfo[CallLogDataSourceIndices.Missed] as? String ?? ""
    if missedCall != "" && Int(missedCall) != nil {
        cell.updateMissedCallIndicator(Int(missedCall)!)
    }

    // Set Job Title
    let jobTitle = callParticipant[ParseKeys.JobTitle.rawValue]
    cell.jobTitle.text = jobTitle as? String

    // Set Date
    if let callDate = callParticipantInfo[CallLogDataSourceIndices.Date] as? String {
        cell.date.text = formatDate(callDate)
        } 
}
```

**Methods used by both view controllers**

```
void downloadImageThenSetForImageView(UIImageView * imageView, NSURL *url) {
[[SDWebImageManager sharedManager] downloadImageWithURL:url options:0
                                               progress:^(NSInteger receivedSize, NSInteger expectedSize) {

                                               }
                                              completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType, BOOL finished, NSURL *imageURL) {
                                                  imageView.image = [UIImage resize:image newSize:imageView.bounds.size];
                                                  }];

}

extension UIImage {
class func resize(bigImage: UIImage, newSize: CGSize) -> UIImage {
    let hasAlpha = false
    let scale: CGFloat = 0.0 // Automatically use scale factor of main screen

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, !hasAlpha, scale)
    bigImage.drawInRect(CGRect(origin: CGPointZero, size: newSize))

    let scaledImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return scaledImage
}
```

SDWebImage: https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage - The image downloader is asynchronous according to their docs.

**Screenshot of Instruments' Time Profiler Analysis**

[image]

I took that screenshot after scrolling several times on the laggy view controller. If I hide the system libraries then it doesn't show anything which leads me to believe there isn't a bottleneck in my code?

Comment: No one can help if you don't post relevant code in your question.

Comment: Point taken, I was hesitant to post relevant code with the question because the code is heavy with functions and trying to post all the function definitions would inundate this question with code. I ended up just posting one delegate method and the main function that is called from it. Hopefully that code will be enough, otherwise I'll just have to upload all the relevant files.

Comment: How do you define `downloadImageThenSetForImageView`?

Comment: I would suggest using the time profiler, and check where in your code the bottleneck is. My guess is that the downloadImageThenSetForImageView is not done asynchronously.

Comment: downloadImageThenSetForImageView is done asynchronously, it is simply just a wrapper for SDWebImage's asynchronous image downloaded and it is used in the viewcontroller where the scrolling is smooth which is odd. But thank you I will check out the time profiler! I edited the post to include the definition of downloadImageThenSetForImageView.

Comment: @SanderSaelmans I used the time profiler and unfortunately it did not illuminate any possible bottlenecks in my code, I just added a screenshot of the time profiler output